# mysql sum value GROUP BY split

Tags: php, mysql

mysql sum GROUP BY

```
ID  NAME    TYPE    TOTAL
1   user1   1       5
2   user1   2       10
3   user2   1       5
4   user2   1       10
5   user3   3       20
6   user2   3       10
.........
```

Total group by **NAME** AND  **TYPE**

i want this result

```
NAME    TYPE1   TYPE2   TYPE3   TYPE4   TYPE5
user1   5       10      0       0       0
user2   15      0       10      0       0
user3   0       0       20      0       0
---------------------------------------------
Total   20      10      30      0       0
```

php and mysql  ((max type 9))
thanks!!!!

DEMO TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `total` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `name`, `type`, `total`) VALUES(1, 'user1', '1', 5),(2, 'user1', '5', 5),(3, 'user1', '2', 5),(4, 'user1', '3', 5),(5, 'user1', '4', 5),(6, 'user1', '1', 10),(7, 'user1', '2', 15),(8, 'user1', '3', 15),(9, 'user1', '4', 15),(10, 'user1', '5', 15),(11, 'user2', '1', 5),(12, 'user2', '5', 5),(13, 'user2', '2', 5),(14, 'user2', '3', 5),(15, 'user2', '4', 5),(16, 'user2', '1', 10),(17, 'user2', '2', 15),(18, 'user2', '3', 15),(19, 'user2', '4', 15),(20, 'user2', '5', 15),(21, 'user3', '1', 5),(22, 'user3', '5', 5),(23, 'user3', '2', 5),(24, 'user3', '3', 5),(25, 'user3', '4', 5),(26, 'user3', '1', 10),(27, 'user3', '2', 15),(28, 'user3', '3', 15),(29, 'user3', '4', 15),(30, 'user3', '5', 15),(31, 'user4', '1', 5),(32, 'user4', '5', 5),(33, 'user4', '2', 5),(34, 'user4', '3', 5),(35, 'user4', '4', 5),(36, 'user4', '1', 10),(37, 'user4', '2', 15),(38, 'user4', '3', 15),(39, 'user4', '4', 15),(40, 'user4', '5', 15),(41, 'user5', '1', 5),(42, 'user5', '5', 5),(43, 'user5', '2', 5),(44, 'user5', '3', 5),(45, 'user5', '4', 5),(46, 'user5', '1', 10),(47, 'user5', '2', 15),(48, 'user5', '3', 15),(49, 'user5', '4', 15),(50, 'user5', '5', 15);
```

Comment: if amount of type values is variable, it's better to do it with php

Comment: @Ashok - no problem.  it's a lot easier to find answers if you know the terminology for what you are trying to do :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    tt.`name` AS NAME,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tt.type = 1 THEN tt.total ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tt.type = 2 THEN tt.total ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tt.type = 3 THEN tt.total ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tt.type = 4 THEN tt.total ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tt.type = 5 THEN tt.total ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tt.type = 6 THEN tt.total ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE6,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tt.type = 7 THEN tt.total ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE7,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tt.type = 8 THEN tt.total ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE8,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tt.type = 9 THEN tt.total ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE9
FROM
    test_table AS tt
GROUP BY
    tt.`name`
```

Comment: Thanks what i need... and more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table